# How to set a form's input text to a specific value in web2py when the form is submitted?

Tags: python, forms, web, web2py

I have a form with two submit button:

```
form=FORM(DIV(INPUT(_name='itemId', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(),IS_LENGTH(maxsize=12)]),
```

INPUT(_type='submit',_value='search',_name='search'), INPUT(_type='submit',_value="random_search",_name='random')))

If the "search" button is pressed then the form is submitted with the itemId value. If the "random_search" button is pressed, the form should set the itemId into a random value and submit the form.
How to implement it? I used form.vars.itemId and it does'nt work. Thanks!

Comment: Please note: [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) and [web.py](http://webpy.org/) are two different web frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see some code and know what you're doing once the form has been submitted (as well as how a random itemId might be generated). Maybe something like this:

```
def index():
    if request.vars.random:
        request.vars.itemId = generate_random_id()
    form = FORM(DIV(INPUT(_name='itemId', _type='text',
        _value=request.vars.itemId if request.vars else '',
        requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_LENGTH(maxsize=12)]),
        INPUT(_type='submit', _value='search', _name='search'),
        INPUT(_type='submit', _value="random_search", _name='random')))
    return dict(message=form.process())
```

Comment: But the form don't display the random id in the form text area.How to do it?

Comment: Are you saying when the results are returned, you want the form to contain the itemId that was submitted to generate the results (whether the itemId was manually submitted or generated randomly)? If so, the above change should do it (it just assigns request.vars.itemId as the value of the itemId input field).